# I want to read a file in my e: drive from asp.net mvc web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to read a file in my e: drive from asp.net mvc application. 
When I try to access it from FileStream Class , file not found exception is thrown. Here is the code.

```
 public byte[] GetEncFile(string path)
    {
        FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(path);
        FileStream encFileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(encFileStream);

        byte[] encFileBytes = reader.ReadBytes((int)fInfo.Length);

        return encFileBytes;
    }
```

Comment: What line is the exception thrown from? Is there any other information in the error?

Comment: make sure to give right path of file..

Comment: on second line "FileStream encFileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);"

Comment: i can access my file on c: drive but not from e: , d:, drives

Comment: On your e: drive being the client or the server?

Comment: My e: drive on server

Comment: Is e: drive a mapped network drive?

Comment: no, it is not mapped to network drive

Comment: "exception is thrown" - please add some details of that exception to your question (type of exception, message), usually that contains important information about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If Drive exists, then you should use

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath
```

Because you might be using virtual path in mathod paramter.

try :

```
FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath(path));
```

will convert virtual path to physical path.

Hope will help.

Comment: That `Server.MapPath` converts a site-relative path to a full physical path. If the OP already knows the full path ("on my E: drive"), then that wouldn't help.